# Final topology of surjective linear map on Banach space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, banach-spaces

Let $L:X\rightarrow Y$ be a surjective linear map from Banach space $(X,||\cdot||_X)$ to vector space $Y$ and denote with $\tau_L$ the final topology on $Y$ induced by $T$.

Is $\tau_L$ equivalent with the topology given by the strongest norm on $Y$ in which $L$ is bounded?

Comment: Is the kernel of $L$ closed?

Comment: Not necessarily. Another phrasing for the question might be "Does the equivalence of the two topologies follow?"

Comment: Is it clear that such a strongest norm exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There exists a norm on $Y$ making $L$ bounded if and only if the kernel of $L$ is closed.

However, $\|y\|_Y = \inf\lbrace \|x\|: L(x)=y\rbrace$ is always a *semi-norm* (that is
$\|y\|_Y$ may be $0$ for $y\neq 0$) which induces the final topology $\tau_L=\lbrace A\subseteq Y: L^{-1}(A)$ is open in $X\rbrace$. This is simple: $\tau_L$ is finer than
the $\|\cdot\|_Y$-topology since $L$ is continuous w.r.t. $\|\cdot\|_Y$. Conversely, if
$y\in A \in \tau_L$ you find $x\in X$ with $L(x)=y$ and since $L^{-1}(A)$ is open there
is $\varepsilon>0$ with $T(B(x,\varepsilon)) \subseteq A$ which implies that $A$ 
contains $B(y,\varepsilon)$.

Comment: So the question is a simple exercise in basic functional analysis. Why there are no downvotes, nor suggestions to close? Is the question such a "research level" one that it is worth answering?

Comment: I agree that this is not research level. Is there any need to close when it is answered and the answer is accepted?

Comment: I don't know whether there is such a need. I am just trying to understand whether there is any consistent attitude in MO to "off-topic" questions.

Comment: Your question has a very simple answer: NO.

Comment: In favour of NOT closing: this is the first discussion you find when you type "final topology" on MO search. This is of "research facilitation" level as many researchers believe (and in many cases rightly) that final topologies are tricky.