# Can a quotient space of a locally convex space have finer topology that its domain?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, topological-vector-spaces

The following is related to [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/162236/final-topology-of-surjective-linear-map-on-banach-space).

Let $X=X'$, as sets, and let $T:X \rightarrow X'$ be a surjective map from a countably infinite-dimensional LCS $X$ to itself and equip $X'$ with the final topology.  Thus, $T$ is a [quotient map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space_(topology)#Quotient_map).

When/(it possible) for the topology of $X'$ to be finer than that of $X$ or contain open sets not in the topology of $X$?

Comment: Yes. Take a metrizable lcs $X_1$ and a non-metrizable lcs $X_2$. Then the projection operator $X_1\times X_2\to X_1$ is not a homeomorphism.

Comment: @TarasBanakh Following your comment, I realized my initial formulation was trivial.  I rephrased the question to better express what I had in mind.

Comment: Ok, then take a metrizable countably-dimensional lcs $X_1$ and the countably dimensional lcs $X_2$ with the strongest lcs topology (it is usually called the space $\varphi)$. Then $X_2$ is the image of $X_1\times X_2$ and algebraically, $X_2$ is isomorphic to $X_1\times X_2$. The space $X_2$ has the finer topology than $X_1\times X_2$ since the topology of $X_2$ is the largest lcs topology on $X_2$.